# Why isnt this add and remove class not working in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Why is this not working? I'm going absolutely nuts.

```
            <span class="fav"></span>

            $('.fav').on('click', function() {
                $(this).addClass('item-selected');
            });

            $('.fav.item-selected').on('click', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('item-selected');
            });
```

BELOW IS FULL CODE. It's the second part that wont undo.

```
        $('.fav').on('click', function() {
            $(this).addClass('item-selected').next('span.notification').toggleClass('show-notification').html("Hello world!");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.show-notification').removeClass('show-notification');
            },4000);
        });

        $('.fav.item-selected').on('click', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('item-selected').next('span.notification').toggleClass('show-notification').html("Goodbye world!");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.show-notification').removeClass('show-notification');
            },4000);
        });
```

Comment: Is .fav element dynamically added?

Comment: Yes, it is added by the click event

Comment: You cannot bind evetn directly to dynamically added element. You need its static parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2):

As you state that the `.fav` element is dynamically appended to the DOM you need to use a delegated event handler. Also note that as you're toggling the class on successive clicks you don't need multiple handlers; you can just use `toggleClass()`. Try this:

```js
$('#container').on('click', '.fav', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('item-selected');
});
```

```css
.item-selected {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="fav">Item</span>
  <span class="fav">Item</span>
  <span class="fav">Item</span>
  <span class="fav">Item</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> It's the second part that wont undo.

This is because your selector `.fav.item-selector` returns no element

Try this

```
 $('.fav').on('click', function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('item-selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('item-selected').next('span.notification').toggleClass('show-notification').html("Goodbye world!");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.show-notification').removeClass('show-notification');
        },4000); 
      }
   });
```

Comment: re-read edit, I think OP got confused, the span isn't dynamically created, the newly class is though ^^

Answer (score 1):

Because a `span` with the class `item-selected` isn't part of the original DOM, which is what jQuery works with. You need to make it more dynamic like this:

HTML:

```
<span class="fav target-click"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.target-click').click(function()
{
    if ($(this).hasClass('item-selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('item-selected')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('item-selected')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code thanks to the help receive in the answers provided.

```
            $(".job-listings").on('click', '.fav', function() {
                $(this).addClass('item-selected').next('span.notification').addClass('show-notification').html("Hello world!");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.show-notification').removeClass('show-notification');
                },1000);
            });

            $(".job-listings").on('click', '.fav.item-selected', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('item-selected').next('span.notification').addClass('show-notification').html("Goodbye world!");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.show-notification').removeClass('show-notification');
                },1000);
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        function callBindEvents()
        {
           $('.fav').unbind('click');
           $('.fav').bind('click', function() {
              $(this).addClass('item-selected');
              callBindEvents();
           });

           $('.fav.item-selected').unbind("click");
           $('.fav.item-selected').bind('click', function() {
               $(this).removeClass('item-selected');
               callBindEvents();  
           });
       }
       $( document ).ready(function() {
        callBindEvents();
      })
```

First time when u were adding onclick events fav.item-selected was not exists. it was added later on, so you need to write onclick event after you added that class to div.